# Modify inline script

Tags: javascript, html

I got this piece of code that is written by the platform I'm using. I can't edited the file directly:

```
<!-- some html -->
<a class="buy-in-page-button" productindex="0" style="display:block" href="javascript:alert('Please, select your size.');">Add to cart</a>
<script>
$('.buy-in-page-button[productindex=0]').buyButton(11, {salesChannel: 1}, {redirect: false, addMessage: 'Produto adicionado com sucesso!', hideUnavailable: true})
</script>
<!-- more html -->
```

I can load a external javascript file on this page. Thought this external javascript file, can I somehow modify the `'Produto adicionado com sucesso!'` part?

Comment: Could you please rephrase what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What is `.buyButton` doing? Are you using a plugin? Which?

Comment: If you're talking about translating text you're going to probably want to look at the google Translate API. There's an article here: https://davidwalsh.name/google-translate-api   - realistically though you may want to go to work on it and come back when you have a more specific question if you can't get it working. Perhaps with a few more details as to what you're using and where this code is coming from.

Comment: Use something like this `$('script')[2].innerHTML.match(/addMessage: '(.*?)'/g)`

Comment: I guess that the buyButton is a jQuery extension. Do you have access to the extensions code? (buyButton.js...?)

Comment: Nop. No access to anything. It's a closed platform. I can only attach another .js file to load on the page and nothing else.

Comment: @almostamachine does the message 'Produto adicionado com sucesso!' show immediatly after the page loads or does it show after a user interaction? If it if shown on page load then you can manually modify it

Comment: @ShaiAharoni it is show on page load. Could you elaborate further?

Comment: @almostamachine can you copy here the rendered HTML with the message ?  Is it inside the <a> tag?

Comment: @ShaiAharoni it's too big to put it here... http://ameyusa.vtexcommercestable.com.br/red-mirror-flare-pants/p

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156700/discussion-between-almostamachine-and-shai-aharoni).